# using images as titles in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view that leads to information from CoreData. For example i have this table View of 3 categories, place 1, place 2, place 3. In place 1, i have stored 3 places and they will appear in a table, to view each place is by selecting them from the table.

Now, i would like to replace all of the titles in the tables with images that i have created. No texts, only image that will take over the whole spacing in the table. Can anyone guide me on how to do so?

this is the code where i try to edit the cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}


NSManagedObject *managedObject = [fetchedResultsController_ objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
UIImage *pimage=[managedObject valueForKey:@"placetableimage"]; 
CGSize size=pimage.size; 
CGFloat ratio = 0; 
if (size.width > size.height) 
{
    ratio = 44.0 / size.width;
} 
else 
{
    ratio = 44.0 / size.height;
}
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(50, 5, ratio * size.width, ratio * size. height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size); 
[pimage drawInRect:rect]; 
cell.imageView.image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make custom table-view cells. You can see [this](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) example which, I think, suits your requirement. Hope it helps...

Comment: i can configure the cells, currently the image that i want is at the left side of the cell. i want the image to take over the whole cell. as in the cell is an image, ive added text and image into that image which i used photoshop to do so, i have set the size to the appropriate size according to the requirements.

Comment: hmm... the fast scrolling table-view example I've provided "draws" images in cells using "drawInRect" command. So, in your case, you'd be drawing the image in the entire cell. I see from your code that you've added accessory view. You don't need that. Go through the link I've provided. I think it'll help...